# Passing Django Queryset in Views to Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I have a Django Views which has some logic for passing the correct category to the template.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = "catalogue/catalogue.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        category = self.kwargs.get("category")
        if category:
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__iexact=category)
        else:
            queryset = Product.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

I can't work out how to pass this to the template, my template code is as below:

```
            {% for product in products %}
            <tr>   
                <td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
                <p>Cooked with chicken and mutton cumin spices</p></td>
                <td><p><strong>£ {{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>
                <td class="options"><a href="#0"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

I am pretty sure my template syntax is wrong, but how do I pass the particular category to the template? So if I have a category called 'Mains' how do I pass all the products for mains to the template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following method

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    some_data = Product.objects.all()
    context.update({'some_data': some_data})
    return context
```

So now, in your template, you have access to `some_data` variable. You can also add as many data updating the context dictionary as you want.

If you still want to use the `get_queryset` method, then you can access that queryset in the template as `object_list`

```
{% for product in object_list %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Items from queryset in ListView are available as `object_list` in the template, so you need to do something like:

```
{% for product in object_list %}
            <tr>   
                <td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
                <p>Cooked with chicken and mutton cumin spices</p></td>
                <td><p><strong>£ {{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>
                <td class="options"><a href="#0"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

You can find details in the [ListView documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). Note a method called `get_context_data` - it returns a dictionary of variables and values, that will be passed to templates. You can always find why it works in this way in the source code.

Comment: even if I add product_list in templates - what's telling the view to pass a particular category? Nothing is defined on the template. For instance, do I need to enter {% for product.mains in product_list %}

Comment: @Rutnet I just noticed that I copypasted your code but didn't change it. Just do `{% for product in object_list %}. I fixed the code example now.

Comment: thanks, but still doesn't answer how I can pass the specific category from the template. How do I get all products that are in a category called 'mains'

Comment: List view passes it to template for you. It passes results of `get_queryset`

Comment: Its returning all the products in database. How do I specify the specific category on the template?

Comment: you need to pass category ID to views arguments in URLs. And use category__pk=self.kwargs.get('category') instead of iexact would be better.

Comment: Sorry, bit confused - could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to pass data to the template context is to use the built-in *view* variable. So rather than overriding the *get_context_data()* method, you can simply create a custom method that returns a queryset:

```
def stores(self):
    return Store.objects.all()
```

Then you can use this in the template:

```
{% for store in view.stores %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

See also:

- https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#new-view-variable-in-class-based-views-context