# Unable to display QuerySet in Django view

Tags: python, django

I was trying to display a QuerySet using method below,
[Passing Django Queryset in Views to Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48544128/passing-django-queryset-in-views-to-template)

I was able to display single object by using get() method, however it returns as a blank page when I try to return all data in the Restaurant Table.

#### Class Restaurant

```py
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    restId = models.AutoField(db_column='restId', primary_key=True)
    restName = models.TextField(db_column='restName')
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.TextField()
    ratings = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    cuisine = models.TextField()
    region = models.TextField()
    #image = models.ImageField()
    last_modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "restaurant"
```

#### views.py

```py
def index_view(request):
    rest_list = Restaurant.objects.all()
    context = {
        'rest_list': rest_list
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#### index.html

```html
    <h1>Index</h1>
    {% for rest in rest_List %}
        {{ rest.restId }}
        {{ rest.restName }}
    {%  endfor %}
```

Comment: What does rest_list prints or returns when you try?

Comment: You made a typo, it is `rest_list` (with `l`, not `L`).

Answer (score 1):

Replace 'index.html' code with below code: Your mistake is a syntax error in 'rest_list'.

```
<h1>Index</h1>
{% for rest in rest_list %}
    {{ rest.restId }}
    {{ rest.restName }}
{%  endfor %}
```

> Python is a case sensitive language.