# How can I return additional data when using a raw query on a model using Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django and have a question in regards to db queries.

I am currently using a raw query to get places within x radius of a given lat lng. My query is

```
   query = """SELECT id, (3959*acos(cos(radians(%2f))
   *cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng)-radians(%2f))
   +sin(radians(%2f))*sin(radians(lat))))
   AS distance FROM businesses_business WHERE approved > 0 HAVING
   distance < %2f ORDER BY %s LIMIT %d OFFSET %d;""" % (
        float(lat),
        float(lng),
        float(lat),
        details['radius'],
        details['orderBy'],
        details['limit'],
        details['offset']
    )
```

and I am serlializing the data using the following:

```
  queryset = Business.objects.raw(query)

  serialized_data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
```

I get back the data which matches the Business model. However, I also want to receive back the distance which is calculated in the query. How could I do this so that the distance for each row is also returned?

Edit: Business model is:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
    lat = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Latitude",
                                          null=True,
                                          blank=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Longitude",
                                          null=True,
                                          blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The business model does not have a `distance` in there and it is being calculated on the fly in the query. The idea is to have multiple businesses and users can search for businesses within x miles of their own lat/lng. I am able to return the businesses that fit the radius criteria however I would also like to show the actual distance too which is what I'm unable to do at the moment.

p.s. If there is a better way to do this then I'd love to hear about it :)

### ANSWER

Finally I figured out how to do this and whilst I was at it, I also managed to find a better way to do the above.

First of all, rather than using the Haversine formula; I used the [GeoDjango Database API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/) to filter items in the db based on distance. This meant that I no longer needed to use raw queries. **HOWEVER** - For this I changed from MySQL to PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extender as it has better functionality for location based queries to be run in SQL. I was able to do this as I was very early on in my project so it didn't have a huge impact.

Below is an example of the GeoDjango API:

```
queryset = Business.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(mi=10)))
                .annotate(distance=Distance("point", pnt))
```

I then added the `distance` to the serializer without adding `distance` to the model:

```
class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    distance = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_distance(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.distance.mi
        except BaseException:
            return None

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'distance')
        model = models.Business
```

Now when I use the `BusinessSerializer` it returns the `distance` too :)

Happy days.

Answer (score 0):

A bit confused:  your query-set should already give you the `id` and the `distance` values. From what I can tell when you serialize it you should already have the value of the `distance`.

Assuming you have a `distance` field in your models, you can just iterate over the returned query-set to see the distance values, e.g.

```
class Person(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(...)
        last_name = models.CharField(...)
        birth_date = models.DateField(...)
    
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
       print(p)
```

This will give all the values in the entity, so you can apply the same logic in your case.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The model itself does not have a `distance` field. The `distance` is being calculated using the `lat`/`long`. If I run the query in mysql, it returns the Id and distance as you mentioned. However, I think the fact that I am using the `.raw()` on `Business` model, it ends up returning the complete business as per the business model.

Comment: @UsmanJ I am not sure about the best method for this since i haven't touched Django in a while. But if clean code is not a worry then simply add a `distance` field to update the value and then return it to the template ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48544816/6505847)). You can of course, just run the query using a driver - directly mapping to the database and then extract the values that way. The database method may also be efficient to avoid recalculating values if the values are already present in the columns and the radius value and business location remains uniform.

Answer (score 0):

The `distance` will be included in the raw sql queryset, but it's probably getting removed by the serializer.

have you tried adding it to the fields attribute in the serializer?

```
serialized_data = serializers.serialize('json', queryset, fields=('name','distance'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, however my model is unaware of what `distance` is and I think that is why even if I put `fields=('name', 'distance')` in the serializer, it doesn't return the distance. It ends up only returning `name`.

Comment: Do you see `distance` if you examine the queryset?  If so you might need to go further in customizing the serializer

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER

Finally I figured out how to do this and whilst I was at it, I also managed to find a better way to do the above.

First of all, rather than using the Haversine formula; I used the [GeoDjango Database API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/) to filter items in the db based on distance. This meant that I no longer needed to use raw queries. **HOWEVER** - For this I changed from MySQL to PostgreSQL with the PostGIS extender as it has better functionality for location based queries to be run in SQL. I was able to do this as I was very early on in my project so it didn't have a huge impact.

Below is an example of the GeoDjango API:

```
queryset = Business.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(mi=10)))
                .annotate(distance=Distance("point", pnt))
```

I then added the `distance` to the serializer without adding `distance` to the model:

```
class BusinessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    distance = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_distance(self, obj):
        try:
            return obj.distance.mi
        except BaseException:
            return None

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'distance')
        model = models.Business
```

Now when I use the `BusinessSerializer` it returns the `distance` too :)

Happy days.